# Different TCP Connection for each WebRequest.Create()

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, httpwebrequest

I have a .net windows service that test network performance by downloading files from a server. I'm using `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri)` to create the HTTP requests.

This service is controlled by a timer. When the timer interval is relatively small, the HTTP requests get blocked by the server.

By looking at packet analyzer, it seems like the TCP connection have been reused. How to request a 'new' TCP connection for each WebRequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting [`HttpWebReqeuest.KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are facing a HTTP-keep alive, so you have to somehow force the `WebClient` not to use it. This is sent as `connection: keep-alive` header from the client and, if the server supports it, connection is kept. See more in Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

So maybe if you send `connection:close` you get a new TCP session on each request.